# How to set NSMutableRequest timeout less than 240 seconds after setting body?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsconnection

I'm creating NSMutableRequest and adding data to body. Heres example how I do it:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL] 
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData 
                                                       timeoutInterval:230.0];
    NSLog(@"Time out interval: %f", request.timeoutInterval); >> Output: 230

    [request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"Time out interval: %f", request.timeoutInterval); >> Output: 240
    [request setTimeoutInterval:230];
    NSLog(@"Time out interval: %f", request.timeoutInterval); >> Output: 240
```

Request timeout after creating it is 230.
After I set body It is 240.
And after I reset it to 230. It is still 240. Timeout value doesn't change unless I set it bigger?

Anyone has any idea why it is happening? How to make timeout interval less than 240 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the iOS you just cannot specify timeout less then 240s in this way (because iPhone could run on a slow connection). For more details check: https://devforums.apple.com/message/108292#108292

If you're really need shorter timeout, you could use NSTimer.
In that case just remember to use asynchronous request, which could be easily canceled.